# Syntax error on javascript due to conversion VS2008 to VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

Recently I installed visual studio 2012. I converted my project in the log it seems to be fine, No errors. When I look in the code in the javascript at the end of the sentence  he marks the ; red and gives the error: "syntax error".  Weirdly of all the line of code still works but I only get this error in VS2012 and not in VS2008. The projects still builds because this is javascript. Any idea why this is marked as an error in VS2012?

```
<link id="Link1" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="Styles/jquery-ui.css" />
<!-- load jQuery and tablesorter scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.json-2.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var publicationTableSiteIDs = <%= getJsonSiteIDs() %>;
        var publicationTableCountries = <%= getJsonCountries() %>;


public string getJsonSiteIDs()
        {   //list to javascript for autocorrect on site id's
            return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(siteIdsList.Distinct().ToList());
        }

        public string getJsonCountries()
        {   //list to javascript for autocorrect on countries
            return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(countryList.Distinct().ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio's editor is trying to parse your interpolated server-side code as Javascript, resulting in a syntax error.

At runtime, the server-side code is properly executed on the server, returning valid Javascript (unless your data has U+2028), so it works fine.